# What is the lifetime of an induced magnetization in a para/diamagnetic material?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields

To the best of my knowledge thermal fluctuations are responsible for washing out any effective magnetization, once the external field is switched off. Since thermal fluctuations need some time to drive the system back to random orientation, what would be the time scale for this process? Is it of the order of 200 ps?